# Is it possible to convert this JQuery code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-analysis

The following code, from the Google-Caja playground,shows two boxes. And once you drag on inside the other the enclosing box changes color:

```
<style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: jQuery is written in JavaScript! YES!

Comment: *"Is it possible to convert this JQuery code to JavaScript?"* Of course. jQuery is a library built with JavaScript. There's **nothing** you can do with jQuery you can't do without it. I'm not saying I'd recommend it, though; jQuery (and other libraries) exist for a reason. ;-)

Comment: @Wiseguy - Yes, that's what I meant. But maybe it was a little naive of me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is with a bit of work. The find, addClass and html ones are easy but the drag and drop is another story. here is a tutorial for it http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can convert absolutely any JavaScript library code to pure JS, since that's what they use after all.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but the .draggable() and .droppable() functions are much too complicated to explain how to do it here. Look at the unminified jQuery UI. That will give you a good start (although it will still be using jQuery).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm looking up " unminified jQuery UI" right now.